# Setting a different image to array

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I am making a menu widget and i need to set each widget with a different image. The widgets are stored in an array. Does anyone know what I could use to set a different image to each instance of the array?

If more info is needed please let me know!

here is the .cpp for the widget

```
#include "iconwidget.h"
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPainterPath>

iconWidget::iconWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    this->resize(ICON_WIDGET_WIDTH,ICON_WIDGET_HEIGHT);
    pressed = false;
}

void iconWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QRect areatopaint = event->rect();
    QPainter painter(this);
    QBrush brush(Qt::black);

    QPointF center = this->rect().center();

    QPainterPath icon;
    icon.addEllipse(center,30,30);
    painter.drawPath(icon);

    if(pressed)
    {
        brush.setColor(Qt::red);
    }

    painter.fillPath(icon, brush);
}

void iconWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = true;
    update();
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void iconWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressed = false;
    update();
    QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

and here is the function that makes the icons and moves them. I just want each icon that is created to have a different image.

```
void zMenuWidget::createAndLayoutIcons(zMenuWidget* const)
{
    int outerRadius = 150;
    int innerRadius = 80;
    int radius = (outerRadius + innerRadius)/2;
    double arcSize = (2.0 * M_PI)/ NUM_ICONS;

    QPointF center;
    center.setX(this->size().width());
    center.setY(this->size().height());
    center /= 2.0;

    //Loop for finding the circles and moving them
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_ICONS; i++)
    {

        icon[i] = new iconWidget(this);

        //Finding the Icon center on the circle
        double x = center.x() + radius * sin(arcSize * i);
        double y = center.y() + radius * cos(arcSize * i);

        x -= ICON_WIDGET_WIDTH/2.0;
        y -= ICON_WIDGET_HEIGHT/2.0;

        //moves icons into place
        icon[i]->move(x-icon[i]->x(),y-icon[i]->y());
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean the widgets are stored in an array? Your question is a little fuzzy to me. 

Why wouldn't an 'image' member variable on your widget class do the trick?

Comment: yes i apologize that is what I meant. Each slot in the array needs to have a different image. I just dont know how to assign an different image to each slot separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your widgets are a class that you've implemented. If that's the case, just add an 'image' member variable (of however you're implementing an image). Then your array stores those widgets.

In pseudo code:

```
class Widget
{
    Image image; //however you represent an image. This could be a BYTE pointer.
    //all your other stuff
};
```

then,

```
Widget widget1;
Widget widget2;
widget1.image = something.jpg;
widget2.image = something_else.jpg;

std::vector<Widget> = {widget1,widget2};
```

Comment: i added some more info. i dont quit understand how i would do this